# Calling a function that uses readline() multiple times

Tags: javascript, node.js, input, readline

**EDITED TO INCLUDE CODE:** -- the functions "generate_answer_je" and "generate_answer_tu" just point to other functions defined in my file...just didn't include them here for space. I'm using Node's readline module to take input from a user in the command line, and run a function with it. After that function has run, I'd like to be able to call it again (taking in another bit of user input). No matter what I try, the function will quit after its first completion, and won't prompt the user for anything after that. Is there something about readline that keeps it from being triggered more than once in a file????

```
var readline = require('readline');
var rl = readline.createInterface(process.stdin, process.stdout);

var pronoun = {
 1: 'je',
 2: 'tu'
}
var verb = {
  1: 'regarder',
  2: 'preparer',

}
var points = {
score : 0
}

function generate_verb(){
  subj = Math.floor((Math.random() * 2) +1);
  inf = Math.floor((Math.random() * 2) +1);

 rl.question(pronoun[subj] + " // " + verb[inf] + ":  ", function(answer){
   if (subj === 1){
      var genVerb = generate_answer_je.call(genVerb, verb[inf]);
    if (answer === correctAnswer) {
      console.log('oui!');
      points.score +=1;
    } else {
      console.log('non!');
    }
 }
 else if (subj === 2){
  var genVerb = generate_answer_tu.call(genVerb, verb[inf]);
  if (answer === correctAnswer) {
    console.log('oui!');
    points.score +=1;
  } else {
    console.log('non!');
  }


 rl.close();
});

}
while (points.score < 10){
 generate_verb();
 }
```

Comment: Please edit your post and include your code so we can try and fix it so it works!

Comment: problem by getting an input from the console in node.js is that in node.js stuff is async. But its feasible I believe

Comment: Thanks-- added my code.